# Total progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

[image]

Im currently coding a Downloader. Now i need to make a Total ProgressBar. But i have no idea how to, i know that i need to calculate the Total Download Size.

Since the Downloads are in a List i could maybe some how bind the progressbar to the Count property of the List. Or is there a better Way of doing that. Heres the Code for the Song ProgressBars.

Sorry for my bad english!

```
private void MainWindow_bytesDownloaded(ByteArgs e, Song songObj) {

            if (songObj != null) {
                gui.Invoke(() => new Action(() => {
                    EditState(State.DOWNLOADING, songObj);

                    foreach (var item in _downloadList) {
                        if (item.SongName == songObj.SongName) {
                            item.Maximum = (int)e.total;
                            item.Value += (int)e.downloaded;
                            AllMaximum += e.total;
                            break;
                        } 
                    }
                }).Invoke());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a ratio.

You know the full length of the bar.
You know the progress of the download (in bytes).
You know the full length of the download (in bytes).

1) For a single download progress...
Solve for x:

```
x/(full_bar_length) = (current_progress)/(full download length)<br>
x = ((current_progress)/(full download length)) * full_bar_length
```

Then bind the length of the progress to x.

---

2) For the case of "Grand total:"

Sum the total bytes across all downloads.
Sum the current bytes downloaded across all downloads.

Solve for x:

```
x/(full_bar_length) = (sum_current_bytes)/(total_bytes_sum)<br>
x = ((sum_current_bytes)/(total_bytes_sum)) * (full_bar_length)
```

Again, bind x to your "grand total current progress".

---

As far as the UI goes, the List (_downloadList) is bound to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding _downloadList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid Margin="10">
          <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="{Binding RatioValue}" Height="50" />
       </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I haven't tried that, but it should be close to what you are asking for -- how to fill a rectangle based on an Item's Value, for each item.

You'll need to add a new property to your Download class, and calculate a RatioValue, based on the Value, and have that be in the item, where the Value property is.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but i know the logic behind it, but since the total bytes are constantly changing becuase the User drops new Songs in, where should i update the progressbar Value in bytesDownloaded?

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ I updated the answer to include some xaml using the object in your example code.